# git diff file between two last commits that changed it

Tags: git

Rephrase: I would like to find the two last commits that changed a specific file (or folder, or group of files if possible) and perform a diff between those two commits. All in one command.

Thanks, this is going to save me time when I try to visualise what are the changes in data files that I re-populate with new scripts.

Comment: I actually wrongly rephrased the title, here's how to do the title question following larsmans' answer: `git diff $(git log --format='%H' -2 -- "$path") -- "$path"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git diff $(git log --format='%H' -2 -- "$path")
```

Where `path` is obviously the path of the file you want to inspect.

Answer (score 0):

```
git diff $(git log -2 --oneline -- MyFile.txt | cut -d " " -f 1)
```